# Basic Authentication using JaxWsDynamicClientFactory

Tags: cxf

I have to use JaxWsDynamicClientFactory since only information available with me is WSDL URL and the method name. Java Contract interface is avilable to me. Call should be straight forward using CXF.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JaxWsDynamicClientFactory factory = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();

    Client client = factory.createClient("service?WSDL");
    try {
        //checkServiceHealth
        client.invoke("checkServiceHealth");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Service is protected via Basic authentication. I can not get through this. I have tried adding policy to conduit already. Still exception hasn't change.

```
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.chooseAlternative(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:172)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.finalizeConfig(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initialize(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:142)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.createEndpointPolicyInfo(PolicyEngineImpl.java:584)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:313)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyDataEngineImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.updateClientPolicy(HTTPConduit.java:318)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.updateClientPolicy(HTTPConduit.java:338)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.getClient(HTTPConduit.java:861)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.configureConduitFromEndpointInfo(HTTPConduit.java:360)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.finalizeConfig(HTTPConduit.java:440)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getConduit(HTTPTransportFactory.java:242)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:222)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.createConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:145)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:107)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:63)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:853)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:511)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:299)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:285)
```

Any help!

Comment: have you tried to register a HTTPConduitConfigurer as bus extension?

Comment: I got through this. But after that I gave up on the idea of using CXF for client call. Making my own SOAP message and shooting with apache http client.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @dennis-kieselhorst, the following code works for performing basic HTTP authentication using `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory`.

Creates an implementation of `HTTPConduitConfigurer` :

```
public static class MyHTTPConduitConfigurer
implements HTTPConduitConfigurer
{
    private final String _username;

    private final String _password;

    public MyHTTPConduitConfigurer(final String username, final String password)
    {
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final String name, final String address, final HTTPConduit c)
    {
        final AuthorizationPolicy authorization = new AuthorizationPolicy();
        authorization.setUserName(_username);
        authorization.setPassword(_password);
        c.setAuthorization(authorization);
        final HttpAuthSupplier supplier = new DefaultBasicAuthSupplier();
        c.setAuthSupplier(supplier);
    }
}
```

Then use it as a bus extension :

```
final MyHTTPConduitConfigurer myHttpConduitConfig = new MyHTTPConduitConfigurer(username, password);
final Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
bus.setExtension(myHttpConduitConfig, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);
final JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance(bus);
try (final Client client = dcf.createClient(wsdlUrl))
{
    // enjoy
}
```